# How do I show that $\frac{\exp(yz)}{\sum_{y'=0}^1\exp(y'z)} =\sigma((2y-1)z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

**Question:** How do I show that $\dfrac{\exp(yz)}{\sum_{y'=0}^1\exp(y'z)} =\sigma((2y-1)z)$ , where $\sigma(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$?

I've tried all kinds of stuff, but I don't get a lot closer than  $\dfrac{\exp(yz)}{\sum_{y'=0}^1\exp(y'z)} = \dfrac{1}{\exp z^{-y} + \exp z^{-y+1}}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That denominator is just $1+e^z$. I don't see any reason why you write it the way you do. Also your expression of $\exp(z^{-y})$ it is an error. There's no way that could come out of your expressions.

Comment: Let's rewrite this in normal notation. You are trying to show $$\frac{e^{yz}}{1 + e^z} = \frac 1{1+e^{(1-2y)z}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-multiply the expression $$\frac{e^{yz}}{1 + e^z} = \frac 1{1+e^{(1-2y)z}}$$ and you get
$$e^{yz}\left(1+e^{(1-2y)z}\right) = 1 + e^z$$
$$e^{yz} + e^{(1-y)z}= 1 + e^z$$
And this shows your formula is false, as the left side depends on $y$, but the right side does not.

Comment: The context of the question (admittedly missing from the OP's description) comes from Ian Goodfellow's text Deep Learning, Section 6.2.2.2 where the values of $y$ are either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @IntegrateThis - Thank you. That is good information to have, and obviously if I had possessed it at the time, I would have given a more complete answer. But even as is, I answered the OP's question, by pointing out to them that the method they were trying to use to understand the equation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is valid for $y=0$ and $y=1$.
Let the equality for $y=0$ be shown as follows:

$\left [ \frac{\exp(yz)}{\sum_{y^{\prime}=0}^{1} \exp(y^{\prime}z)} \right ]_{y=0}=\left [ \frac{\exp(yz)}{1 + \exp(z)} \right ]_{y=0}=\frac{1}{1 + \exp(z)}$

$\left [\sigma((2y-1)z) \right ]_{y=0}=\left [ \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(2y-1)z)}\right ]_{y=0}= \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(-1)z)}=\frac{1}{1 + \exp(z)}$

Hence, the equality for $y=0$ has been shown.

Now, let the equality for $y=1$ be shown as follows:

$\left [ \frac{\exp(yz)}{\sum_{y^{\prime}=0}^{1} \exp(y^{\prime}z)} \right ]_{y=1}=\left [ \frac{\exp(yz)}{1 + \exp(z)} \right ]_{y=1}=\frac{\exp(z)}{1 + \exp(z)}$

$\left [\sigma((2y-1)z) \right ]_{y=1}=\left [ \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(2y-1)z)}\right ]_{y=1}= \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(2-1)z)}=\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-z)}=\frac{\exp(z)}{1 + \exp(z)}$

Hence, the equality for $y=1$ has been shown, as well.

This equality should be considered in the context of binary classification using neural networks. In the binary classification, the target variable $y$ can take on only the values $0$ or $1$.

A discussion exists in the section "6.2.2.2 Sigmoid Units for Bernoulli Output Distributions" of the book at https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question for readers of the relevant textbook.